# Careers site score display error

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, user-interface

There is a display error of completeness score in the right sidebar of the careers site. The error is seen on all pages of profile (e.g. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/score/138181). A pair of screen shots of the error attached. First contains the error score (149/210) in the sidebar. Second contains the actual score (151/210) at the bottom grand total.

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**:

**REPRODUCTION STEPS**:

In the **Stack Exchange** section has 20 points in total, where 10 points are for linking to 5 or more Stack Exchange answers. I have exactly 5 answers linked. My total score should be 151/210. And it is.

Now, on the edit profile page, I remove the bottom-most link, the score changes to 149/210. Then I link an answer (the same one or any other), the total score still remains 149/210, whereas it should be 151/210. **I think this is an error/bug, if I am not wrong**. Even more, when I refresh this page, the score does not still start displaying correctly. And, if I don't do the following, the score is still the incorrect one. (My profile score is incorrect at present).

Now, there is another bug as well. From the same point above, I click the `View completeness report` link. On reaching the page, I still am seeing my score to be 149/210 and not 151/210. This is the same as depicted in the images above. But, as soon as I refresh this page, the score starts displaying correctly.

**UPDATE 2**

The score in green does not get refreshed immediately, but the score in black below gets. Please have a look.

[image]

Comment: I'd wager the score there is cached. Wait a little while.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I had seen this past a week. Today, I tried a lot many things. Sometimes it came back to normal instantly and again started showing the problem. I am trying to note down a list of reproducible steps. Would update the same once I am done.

Comment: Closing as duplicate. We've had this problem for a while, it should be fixed by now. Please let us know if there are any further incorrect scores.

Comment: @Max I am still facing the problem. Would write down the exact reproduction steps for the problem. If possible, please have a look at my profile. Its in the exact state as depicted in the above images. Thanks.

Comment: @SandipAgarwal The fix was deployed today. I just checked your profile and it should now display the correct score. Thanks for your feedback, let us know if there are any more problems!

Comment: @Max I am still receiving the problem in a similar format. I have updated the question to list down the reproduction steps. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @SandipAgarwal You're right, this issue is actually different from the one which got fixed last week. Reopening, we'll look into this. Note that, as you're pointing out correctly, refreshing the completeness report will recalculate your score to the correct value. So this be done as a workaround in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. No more incomplete completeness scores, hopefully!

So, what was the problem? Well, when you added a new Stackoverflow question to your profile, we recalculated your completeness score, and then added the question. What we should have done instead is, add the question *first*, and *then* recalculate the score. Just like we drink orange juice *first*, and *then* brush our teeth. Makes sense? :-) Anyways, thanks for reporting this issue and let us know if there are any more problems!

Comment: I am still receiving the error in part now. UPDATE 2 above explains it in an image attached. Thanks.

Comment: So the score calculation is now correct, it just doesn't refresh the upper label until you reload the page - right?

Comment: Please try again. The score in the sidebar should now get updated instantaneously after adding or removing a SO question.

Comment: Bingo! Everything working now. :-) Would let you know if the problem persists or new one arises.